# On some posts scrolling all the way down in the answers tab causes iOS app to crash

Tags: bug, ios-app, scrolling

On [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/34968/caveman-duels-or-me-poke-you-with-sharp-stick) post if you scroll all the way down in the answers tab, the app crashes. This leads me to believe it happens on other posts will an excessive amount of answers.

Comment: Try viewing the [Formatting Sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) on your app.